# Using jQuery to validate checkboxes and input text values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need your help,

Is there a way one can possible use the all so powerful jQuery to validate the following conditions before enabling button?

1. If the user inputs a value in the text box and then checks one of the checkboxes, then enable the button
2. If the user already has a value present in the text, and then checks one of the checkboxes, then enable the button

How can this be written in jQuery, from my perspective this would some lenghty form field checking no?

Here's the HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Add To Calendar" disabled>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="dategroup"><input type="text" id="date1">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="dategroup"><input type="text" id="date2">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="dategroup"><input type="text" id="date3">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, jQuery - as well as plain JavaScript - can definitely do this. Where did you get stuck, how far did you get, what went wrong, *how* did it "*go wrong*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started. You can make the field validation as complex or simple as you wish.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
   var tmp = $(this).next('input').val();
   //validate tmp, for example:
   if (tmp.length > 1){
     //alert('Text field has a value');
     $('#mybutt').prop('disabled',false);
   }else{ 
     //alert('Please provide a long value in text field');
     $('#mybutt').prop('disabled', true);
     $(this).prop('checked',false);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input id="mybutt" type="button" value="Add To Calendar" disabled>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="dategroup"><input type="text" id="date1">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="dategroup"><input type="text" id="date2">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="dategroup"><input type="text" id="date3">
```

Comment: @mmcrae No, I don't think that's it... I use that ID in examples and it usually goes over with a grin. Suspect it's because I answered a question where OP hadn't tried anything himself. *I don't care about that, though, because I was there once myself and remember it well.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
$('input').on('change input', function() {
  $input = $('input');
  $button = $('input[type="button"]');
  var arr = [];
  $input.each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('type') !== 'button') {
      arr.push(check($(this)));
      arr.indexOf(false) == -1 ? $button.removeAttr('disabled') : $button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  })
})

function check(elem) {
  if ($(elem).attr('type') == 'checkbox' && $(elem).is(':checked')) return true;
  if ($(elem).attr('type') == 'text' && $(elem).val().trim().length) return true;
  return false;
}
```

```js
$('input').on('change input', function() {
  $input = $('input');
  $button = $('input[type="button"]');
  var arr = [];
  $input.each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('type') !== 'button') {
      arr.push(check($(this)));
      arr.indexOf(false) == -1 ? $button.removeAttr('disabled') : $button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  })
})

function check(elem) {
  if ($(elem).attr('type') == 'checkbox' && $(elem).is(':checked')) return true;
  if ($(elem).attr('type') == 'text' && $(elem).val().trim().length) return true;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Add To Calendar" disabled>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="dategroup">
<input type="text" id="date1">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="dategroup">
<input type="text" id="date2">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="dategroup">
<input type="text" id="date3">
```